Issue with PATCH request resulting in 404 error when updating a product in a Node.js Express CRUD application
I'm encountering an issue with updating products in a Node.js Express CRUD application using a PATCH request. When attempting to update a product through the frontend, I consistently receive a 404 error.
Problem Description:
I have a frontend React application that communicates with a Node.js Express backend to perform CRUD operations on a DynamoDB database. The backend provides an API endpoint for updating products, and the frontend triggers this endpoint using axios for HTTP requests.
Expected Behavior:
When I click the "Update" button on the frontend, the selected product should be updated in the database, and the product list should be refreshed to reflect the changes.
Steps Taken:

Verified that the product exists in the database.
Checked the backend route configuration, which seems to be correctly set up to handle PATCH requests.
Reviewed the frontend code to ensure that the correct product ID is being passed in the PATCH request payload.

Code Snippets:
Backend Route:
router.patch('/', async (req, res) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: dynamodbTableName,
    Key: {
      'productId': req.body.productId
    },
    UpdateExpression: `set ${req.body.updateKey} = :value`,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':value': req.body.updateValue
    },
    ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'
  }
  await dynamodb.update(params).promise().then(response => {
    const body = {
      Operation: 'UPDATE',
      Message: 'SUCCESS',
      UpdatedAttributes: response
    }
    res.json(body);
  }, error => {
    console.error('Do your custom error handling here. I am just ganna log it out: ', error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  })
})

Frontend Update Function:
  const updateProduct = async () => {
    if (!selectedProduct) return; // Check if a product is selected for update
    try {
      console.log('About to update the product with ID:', selectedProduct.productId);
      await axios.patch(`http://nodejs-express-crud-env.eba-uqag2f9z.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/product/${selectedProduct.productId}`, {
        productId: selectedProduct.productId,
        updateKey: 'productName',
        updateValue: productName 
      });
      fetchProducts(); // Update product list after updating
      setSelectedProduct(null); // Clear selected product state
      setProductId('');
      setProductName('');
      setProductPrice('');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating product:', error);
    }
  };

Request URL in Frontend:
axios.patch('axios.patch(`http://nodejs-express-crud-env.eba-uqag2f9z.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/product/${selectedProduct.productId}', { /* Payload */ });

Additional Information:

The frontend uses axios for making HTTP requests to the backend.

Request for Assistance:
I'm seeking guidance on troubleshooting this issue and identifying the root cause of the 404 error when attempting to update products through the frontend. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

In your Backend Route - is router a module? If so how have you exported, imported and mounted it?

@jQueeny Yeah, I have imported the router module as const router = express.Router();

Can you show the code where you import it and then mount it then?
